# JetBrains Products: Create a file that includes all shortcut keys

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to customize shortcut-keys in one JetBrains product, and I want to save these customizations in a file, and use it in all JetBrains products (so I won't be able to customize it again). DO you know whether it's possible?

Comment: @CrazyCoder should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your keymap changes are already stored in the `.xml` file under [config](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) directory, `keymaps` subdirectory.

You can copy this file manually, use `File` | `Export Settings` / `Import Settings` or use the [Settings Repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/settings-repository.html) to share it between the IDEs.